file samples into frame : avcodec_fill_audio_frame
Rust binding https://github.com/larksuite/rsmpeg of ffmpeg.
I try to fill AVFrame with samples as below.
let bgm_samples : AVSamples = ...;
assert_eq!(bgm_samples.nb_channels, 1);
assert_eq!(bgm_samples.sample_fmt, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP);

let mut frame = AVFrame::new();
frame.set_nb_samples(bgm_samples.nb_samples);
frame.set_ch_layout(AVChannelLayout::from_nb_channels(1).into_inner());
frame.set_format(bgm_samples.sample_fmt);
frame.set_sample_rate(22050);

frame
    .alloc_buffer()
    .context("Could not allocate frame buffer")?;

let raw_ptr = frame.into_raw();
unsafe {
    let err = ffi::avcodec_fill_audio_frame(
        raw_ptr.as_ptr(),
        1,
        bgm_samples.sample_fmt,
        bgm_samples.audio_data[0].as_mut().unwrap(),
        bgm_samples.nb_samples
            * ffi::av_get_bytes_per_sample(bgm_samples.sample_fmt),
        0,
    );
    if err < 0 {
        bail!("avcodec_fill_audio_frame failed with {}", err);
    }
}

let frame = unsafe { AVFrame::from_raw(raw_ptr) };

The frame from above code would cause an error in encoder:

[aac @ 0000021A08201AC0] Input contains (near) NaN/+-Inf

If I change the above code as below, to copy samples into an AVAudioFifo and then read samples from AVAudioFifo into AVFrame, it works!  It means the bgm_samples contains valid samples. But somehow avcodec_fill_audio_frame does not copy the samples correctly.
Can someone help?  thanks in advance.
let mut fifo: AVAudioFifo = AVAudioFifo::new(
    bgm_samples.sample_fmt,
    1,
    bgm_samples.nb_samples,
);

unsafe {
    fifo.write(bgm_samples.audio_data.as_ptr(), bgm_samples.nb_samples)?;
}

// create frame from samples
let mut frame = AVFrame::new();
frame.set_nb_samples(bgm_samples.nb_samples);
frame.set_ch_layout(AVChannelLayout::from_nb_channels(1).into_inner());
frame.set_format(bgm_samples.sample_fmt);
frame.set_sample_rate(22050);

frame
    .alloc_buffer()
    .context("Could not allocate frame buffer")?;

if unsafe { fifo.read(frame.data_mut().as_mut_ptr(), bgm_samples.nb_samples)? }
    < bgm_samples.nb_samples
{
    bail!("Could not read data from FIFO");
}

